# Common place to add methods

Tags: grails, groovy

I am a newbie to Grails and still learning the ropes! The application that i work on uses services.

My task is to add a new method in one of the **services** and have it get called from clients.

This new method is going to be pretty long and i don't want all the method body to be in the **service** class.

I would like to add another method in a place other than this service to do all the calculations for this new method.

Which is the best place to add a method like that? Should i add a new domain? Or just a controller class?

I don't want any of the information in the new method to be saved to database.

A sample code look like this:

```
class MyService {

    String getDomainName(String ID) {
        return domainNameGenerator(ID);
     }

}
```

Now i want to put the **domainNameGenerator** method into another place.

Comment: It really depends on what `domainNameGenrator` does. If it's just plan Groovy or Java code then place it in your `src/groovy` or `src/java`.

Comment: It's just going to be Groovy/Java code and nothing to do with Views (GSP) files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your standalone code in `src/groovy` or `src/java` depending on the actual language of your code, but there's nothing wrong with putting code in the service class itself. If the new class and the service `package` is the same, you don't even have to add an `import`.